# Swimming with Fins Versus Elite Swimmers

Tags: technique, swimming, freestyle

When sprinting with fins, and especially now that I'm trying to press my chest and head down and get my hips up, I can feel a pretty significant amount of drag as my arm recovers. I think this is due to the bowl of water I'm lying in because the fins are so powerful.

However, this is what elite swimmers have to deal with to a degree even without the fins, and dealing with it even at my level is probably helpful. How do they prevent the most drag as their arms are coming forward in the recovery part of the stroke?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're asking here just a bit?

Comment: I thought it was straightforward. Can you tell me what's not clear about it? Basically, my arms have to move through a lot of water that is up and to the side of my body as they recover.

Comment: I know you probably have tons of questions, but it might help to slow down and see what kind of answers you get here before you ask too many more. We don't have a *huge* expert community of swimmers yet (though we'd definitely like to add some). So it might take a bit before you get answers, and the more you flood in questions, the more overwhelmed a potential expert might be. It might help to slow down and focus on asking questions as clear and detailed as possible.

Comment: :). I was about to post a fourth question (would have been my last), but I decided it wasn't as important and stopped for the same reason you stated. I checked the swimming tag before I posted, but I figure experts will eventually start congregating here and there are probably a few here. A little background, I stopped swimming for 4.5 years after high school, and as I get back into it, I'm trying to work on technique. I have a meet in a week and a half in which I'm trying to break my times, and it's hard to find consistent technique answers, hence all the questions.

Comment: I would like to add this as a comment but I don't have enough points.
As far as I understand the recovery part of the stroke, your arm has completed the underwater portion of the stroke and is out of the water and being pulled forward in order to prepare for re-entry into the water. So for that definition your question does not make sense - drag caused by air is negligible. I know the freestyle stroke as entry->catch->pull->push->recovery with a rough definition given here: http://www.sharecare.com/health/swimming/what-the-different-swim-stroke . Please explain which part of the stroke you def

Comment: I define recovery how you define it: the arm being out of the water and moving back to the front of the body. There is such a huge wake created by the fins that I'm literally lying in a bowl of water, so my arm has to pass through the walls to do a normal recovery.

Comment: Perhaps more rotation is required at those speeds and a higher elbow instead of the low winglike recovery.

Comment: Again this should be a comment and not an answer:
I swim in openwater as well as in the pool and too be honest I've never had a problem with my arm dragging in the water no matter how rough the water. Maybe I'm just not fast enough. Even the guys at my club who can swim 1000m in 12 minutes have never complained about this. Do you have a high elbow recovery (like this http://coachpete.files.wordpress.com/2008/01/freestyle3.png ) or are you a swinger (like this http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-S2lEbOcjQxY/Ugy8sQSRT8I/AAAAAAAADH4/Jy9IEqq-5VQ/s1600/shelley-arms.jpg). Maybe you could try to switch to the

Comment: I swing. I guess it's not as big of a deal as I'm making it. It's only with fins, which is much faster than regular pace.

Comment: Actually I might only swing with one lol. I can't remember. I'll check tonight

Comment: What fins do you use? Because there are several types of fines and not all are made for swimming? Exercise fins (http://i.ebayimg.com/t/Speedo-Short-Blade-Swim-Swimm-Ubungs-Flossen-/00/s/NTAwWDUwMA==/z/iiwAAMXQVT9SuaVB/$_35.JPG) Diving fins (http://www.billigergo.de/images/products/gross/TusaFF-22.jpg) Apnea fins (http://www.oceanline.biz/contents/media/l_14300.jpg)???? The info is important to answer your question correctly

Comment: @Phil Fins similar to these http://www.aquagear.com/images/sealion.jpg

Comment: okay the fine is to long for swimmtrainig. You should use Exercise fins (i.ebayimg.com/t/Speedo-Short-Blade-Swim-Swimm-Ubungs-Flossen-/…) to improve your kick. The fine you use gives to to much propulsion so you need more power in your armes to get them infront of your body. This sort of fines you use without arms.

Comment: Forgot to come back here. Thanks @Phil. You're probably right.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen your most of the questions @ millie and I've come up with few flaws you may be suffering from. Please identify which suites best in your case.

1. Your head+back+hip are in bow(arc) like position when you do free style without fins.
2. Probably your legs a not stretched enough . May be because of foot make angle of 90 degree with your legs OR your knees are bent. This point is because of you just said with fins your back and hips are in proper position without pressing your chest. Simply means your legs are not stretched enough.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what fins you use, your arm position should never be such that your freestyle recovery is in the water. If the bow wave is high for you, rotate your shoulders more and raise your elbow higher.

Your coach should be pointing this out to you. If you are raising your arms, you don't want to be pressing your chest and head down.

You may wish to discontinue use of fins, or possibly switch to shorter fins (as per @Phil's comment) in order to focus on your arm stroke.